# Calculating chromatic polynomial of a general graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

**Proposition** 5.3.4 from *Introduction to Graph Theory, Second Edition, Douglas B. West*.

Let $x_{(r)} = x(x-1)...(x-r+1)$. If $p_{r}(G)$ denotes the number of partitions of $V(G)$ into $r$ non empty independent sets, then $\displaystyle\chi(G;k) = \sum_{r=1}^{n(G)} p_{r}(G)k_{(r)}$, which is a polynomial in $k$ of degree $n(G).$

***Proof.*** When $r$ colors are actually used in proper coloring, the color classes partition $V(G)$ into $r$ independent sets, which can happen in $p_{r}(G)$ ways. When $k$ colors are available, there are exactly $k_{(r)}$ ways to choose colors and assign them to classes. All the proper colorings arise in this way, so the formula is correct.

Since $k_{(r)}$ is a polynomial in $k$ and $p_{r}(G)$ is a constant for each r, this formula implies that $\chi(G;k)$ is a polynomial of function $k$. When $G$ has $n$ vertices, there is exactly one partition of $G$ into $n$ independent sets and no partition using more sets, so the leading term is $k^n$.

**Doubts**:

1. What is $r$ here? Is it the bare minimum number of colors required to *properly* color a graph?
2. Is there any general formula for calculating $p_{r}(G)$ itself?

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you, if you would write out the proof & tell us what part(s) you don't understand.

Comment: Ok. I will write the proof as given in the book in the question.

Comment: I don't think $r$ has to be the bare minimum. It seems to me that $r$ can be any integer that is at least as big as the bare minimum. There is no "formula" for calculating the chromatic polynomial, but there is a recurrence for calculating it, based on the "deletion-contraction" formula; my guess is that something similar is true for $p_r(G)$. But let's hope someone who knows this stuff better than I do shows up to write a definitive answer.

Comment: Yes, I know about the chromatic recurrence theorem but I'm more interested in proving this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, $r$ is the index variable on the summation $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{n(G)}$. It does not have to be the chromatic number of $G$. Everything said in the proof about it can be said for any integer $r$ (though if $r$ is less than the chromatic number, it is trivially true, because we will end up with $p_r(G)=0$). The idea is that if $p_r(G)$ counts the number of partitions into $r$ independent sets, then $p_r(G) k_{(r)}$ counts the number of $k$-colorings of $G$ in which exactly $r$ colors are used; then, we sum over all values of $r$ to get the total number of $k$-colorings.

I expect that the reason the formula is mentioned is that it is the easiest demonstration of why the chromatic polynomial really is a polynomial. I am not aware of a nice formula for $p_r(G)$; I am not sure that it does not exist, but I am fairly certain that it is not *easier* to calculate than the chromatic polynomial. (West also mentions that "computing the chromatic polynomial in this way is not generally feasible".) Of course, once we compute the chromatic polynomial, we can write it in the $x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}, x_{(3)}, \dots$ basis and extract $p_1(G), p_2(G), p_3(G), \dots$ as the coefficients of the basis elements.

To calculate the chromatic polynomial, deletion-contraction (as outlined in Theorem 5.3.6) is the way to go. Sometimes it is possible to take shortcuts along the way by splitting $G$ up as two smaller graphs joined along a clique (see exercise 5.3.13).